# How to shift control from one uiview to another in touchesMoved method on iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview

Hi I am new in iPhone dev. Please could any body tell me if I have two views one on another and I want that when I click super view it will drag and when I click subview it will drag.  Can anybody help me?

Here is my code:

```
-(void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *aTouch = [touches anyObject];
    //UITouch *aTouchSuper = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [aTouch locationInView:self.view];

    //CGPoint locationSuper=[aTouchSuper locationInView:viewForTouch];


  [UIView beginAnimations:@"Dragging A DraggableView" context:nil];




    ////////////////////////
    //if(location.x>50 &&location.x<300 ){
//      viewForTouch.frame = CGRectMake(location.x,0, 
//                                      viewForTouch.frame.size.width, viewForTouch.frame.size.height);
//    
//
//
//  }
    UIView *subview = [self.view hitTest:[[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view] withEvent:nil];

    NSLog(@"%i",subview.tag);
    if (location.x <= 50) 
    {
        location.x = 50;
    }
    if (location.x >= 300) 
    {
        location.x = 300;
    }
    if(subview.tag==12){

        viewForTouchInner.frame = CGRectMake(location.x,0, 

                                             viewForTouchInner.frame.size.width, viewForTouchInner.frame.size.height);
    }
    if(subview.tag==11) 
    {
        viewForTouch.frame = CGRectMake(location.x,0, 
                                        viewForTouch.frame.size.width, viewForTouch.frame.size.height);
    }



    ///////////////////////
    //if(viewForTouchInner.hidden=FALSE){
//  
//      
//      
//      
//      location.x=0;
//      NSLog(@"%f",location.x);
//      viewForTouchInner.frame = CGRectMake(location.x,0, 
//          
//                                      viewForTouch.frame.size.width, viewForTouch.frame.size.height);
//      
//  
//  }
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    [buttonForMove addTarget:self action:@selector(Show) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

Comment: but why are you using -(void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event { }. this method is use to get the touch event from images. from custom class tab change your view to UIcontroll than it will get touch event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is my code to drag view on superview in ios.
    Suppose i have a button on subview.when this button tapped this action called.It check if subview is placed at x==0 it animated it to x=260,and vice versa
Note also you must add framework QuartzCore/QuartzCore and #import QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h in .m file of your action.setAnimationDuration show duration of dragging
    -(IBAction)listButtonTapped{

```
    // [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    //[self.profileTableView reloadData];
    NSLog(@"ButtonTapped");
    if(profileView.frame.origin.x == 0){
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"advancedAnimations" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:3.0];
        CGRect aFrame = profileView.frame;
        aFrame.origin.x = 260;
        profileView.frame = aFrame;

        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
    else{

        [UIView beginAnimations:@"advancedAnimations" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:3.0];
        CGRect aFrame = profileView.frame;
        aFrame.origin.x = 0;
        profileView.frame = aFrame;

        [UIView commitAnimations];


    }



}
```

[image]
 here button press and view is dragging towards increasing x position
[image]

here image end dragging process
Now if you again press button above white subview left side it will again come on x=0 position.
I hope it will help you!